# Yii2 afterFind() on empty result

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I overloaded in one of my models the afterFind() function:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    echo "<PRE>";
    echo var_dump($this);
    echo "</PRE>";
    die();
}
```

I get the dump in case that the query result is NOT empty.

But this is not getting called in case that the query that gets executed returns no result.

I need to call it especially in the case that no result is found to try to load the requested data via a different source then.

How can i achieve this?

[EDIT]

Find gets called by:

```
return $this->hasOne(Myclass::className(), ['id' => 'key_id']);
```

since hasOne(...) uses

```
public function hasOne($class, $link)
{
    /* @var $class ActiveRecordInterface */
    /* @var $query ActiveQuery */
    $query = $class::find();
    $query->primaryModel = $this;
    $query->link = $link;
    $query->multiple = false;
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Show the controller action (or function) where you di the find()..please

Comment: Is there no way to check if data exists before this query and split your logic as you want there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **::find()** method is from ActiveRecord class and creates your ActiveQuery object
2. **->afterFind()** method is from ActiveQuery class/object, but it gets triggered only in case query returns non-empty result

If you need to do some action regardless of whether query returned result or not, you can:

1. Simply use your relation method

> $query = $this->hasOne(Myclass::className(), ['id' => 'key_id']);
>
> // Do your stuff here and...
>
> return $query;

2. If you search for some more global solutions, then you can extend **yii\db\ActiveRecor**d inside your own active record class, e.g. **app\components\MyActiveRecord** and override **__get** method. Then use **MyActiveRecord** as a base class for your models (**Myclass** in your example) instead of usual **ActiveRecord**.

> namespace app\components;
>
> class MyActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
>
> ```
> public function __get($name)
> {
>     if (isset($this->_attributes[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $this->_attributes)) {
>         return $this->_attributes[$name];
>     } elseif ($this->hasAttribute($name)) {
>         return null;
>     } else {
>         if (isset($this->_related[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $this->_related)) {
>             return $this->_related[$name];
>         }
>         $value = parent::__get($name);
>         if ($value instanceof ActiveQueryInterface) {
>             $result = $this->_related[$name] = $value->findFor($name, $this);
>             // Do your stuff here.
>             return $result;
>         } else {
>             return $value;
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```